# SQL Server - Replace

Tags: sql-server, replace

What's the problem with my query, it doesn't work

```
DECLARE @_old nvarchar = '@35_D'
DECLARE @_new nvarchar = '@Dima'
UPDATE       ShoppingComment SET Commnet =Replace(Commnet,@_old,@_new)
```

It doesn't show error, but query isn't replace, but when I use it without DECLARE , it works fine

Comment: what doesn't work.Can you please elaborate

Comment: Does it give an error message? Does it update to the wrong thing? There is no `where` clause on that statement, is that an issue?

Comment: @Brad it doesn't show error, but query isn't replace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Datatype` length is missing in your code.

From [**MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186939.aspx)

> When *n* is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration
>   statement, the default length is 1.

So only the first character will be assigned to the variable

```
DECLARE @_old nvarchar(50) = '@35_D' --here
DECLARE @_new nvarchar(50) = '@Dima' --here 
UPDATE       ShoppingComment SET Commnet =Replace(Commnet,@_old,@_new)
```